# Disadvantage when exercising with recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I'm doing the following exercise:

Example:

```
"abcde"
```

Output:

```
a
 b
  c
   d
    e
```

Here the template code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* diag(char* str, char* r)
{
    /* Write code */
    r[0] = '\0';
    return r;
}

int main (void)
{
    char str [] = "abcde";
    int n = strlen(str);

    char* r = malloc(n * n + 1);

    r = diag(str, r);

    puts(r);

    free(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Someone could guide me a little the function must be recursive, not know how to start

Comment: Start with a simple article like [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson16.html)

Answer (score 1):

The trick with recursion is to consider what condition you need to make the necessary changes.  You've already gotten everything set up, now think about how you would increment the array so that you can assign the letters to the diagonal positions (there's a pattern).  There also needs to be a terminating case.

Comment: Yep, the key with recursion is you need three things: Setup, recursive call with logic based on the type of operation (typically breaking the initial problem into sub-problems), and the terminating case. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
printDiagonally(char* s, int low, int high){
  if(low < high){
      int i;
      for(i=0 ; i<low; i++)
          printf(" ");
       printf("%c\n", *s);
       printDiagonally(++s, low+1, high);
   }
}
```